# Add individual user to sudoers file using SSSD in Ubuntu?

Tags: sssd

I've set up SSSD on one of our Linux VMs and added an AD group to the sudoers file. That works fine. The issue I'm having is I have another user who is not in the group that needs sudo access.

I added %firstname.lastname ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL to the bottom of the sudoers file but when he trys he gets an error saying he's not in the file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The command to add a user to sudoers is:

```
sudo adduser <username> sudo
```

You need to run this command from a user who already has sudo privileges.

Otherwise, you need to run the command `adduser <username> sudo` as the root user.